# PHPMyAdmin Error- MySQLIi extension missing (Windows)

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I'm running the latest versions of Apache, php and MySQL on a Windows 10 device and am stuck at the PHPMyAdmin Error "mysqli extension is missing".
I've tried everything from un-commenting the extensions to changing the directory and restarting Apache but even though I can see the mysqli.dll file, the error doesn't go away. phpinfo() shows mysqlnd as active. 
Can anyone tell me if there's anything else I can do?
Thanks!

Comment: I understand that you are using latest version, but I would like to know the `php` version

Comment: I'm using 7.2, VC15

Comment: Looks like a version conflict, try reinstalling from official website http://www.wampserver.com/en/

Comment: Reinstalling seems to have worked. Thank you!